# What permissions, across all layers, are necessary to access the SSRS ReportServer web service URL?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, reporting-services, active-directory, windows-server

First of all - SSRS permissions are a nightmare. Just need to put that out there.

Context - I have a set up an ASP.NET WebForms app with a ReportViewer control so login prompts will stop popping up for users. SSRS is 2014, Native Mode, and all DB connections use a domain service account. Authentication is setup as RSWindowsNTLM only.

My app is running in IIS with application pool identity. My machine$ has access within the SSRS portal to the specific reports and folders (wide open actually).

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is different between my production and development servers. Production works fine, but in development, I get a 401 UNLESS I add my machine account to the Administrators group on the SSRS box. This is not necessary in production.

What should I be checking to understand what is different between these two boxes? What layer am I missing? Obviously, it shouldn't be necessary since it's fine in production.

I appreciate any help that can be offered.

Comment: Are the development and production environments in the same AD? Probably start by looking in the ReportServer$INSTANCE.dbo.Users table and comparing the accounts and SIDs between them. Then compare the Roles and PolicyUserRole records against Catalog (which contains all the "Folders," Data Sources, Reports, etc.) to see if objects have been permissioned differently. As with most things in Windows/AD, SSRS can be much easier to manage if you use group-based permissions everywhere instead of trying to manage individual users.

Comment: "*SSRS permissions are a nightmare.*" - Your problem sounds more like general AD / web app server permissions related, and not SSRS's fault. Technically you're talking about AD permissions, not SSRS permissions which are an internal construct in SSRS.